# Error in UseMethod("select") : no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "logical"

Tags: r

I would like to create a list containing each "X4" colum from each of the 5 imputed datasets (imputation made with  the `amelia()` package) contained in the `my_data_im$imputations` list. I'm getting the following output:

`> list_im_prep_A <- lapply(my_data_im$imputations, function(x) x %>% select("X4"))  Error in UseMethod("select") :  no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "logical"`

Sometimes i get the error and sometimes i don't... Any idea for solving this issue?

Thanks in advance!

```
### my code
library("tcltk")
library("Rcpp")
library("readxl")
library("carData")
library("car") 
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("broom")
library("ggplot2")
library("Amelia")
library("tidyverse")
library("ggpubr")
library("rstatix")
library(wrapr)
theme_local <- theme_minimal

### setwd("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Article ")

### my_data <- read_excel("DATA.xlsx")

my_data <- wrapr::build_frame(
   "ID"   , "1", "2", "3", "4"     , "5" |
     "P1" , 100, 100, 100, 40      , 60  |
     "P2" , 100, 60 , 80 , 80      , 40  |
     "P3" , 100, 100, 100, 100     , 100 |
     "P4" , 40 , 90 , 60 , 40      , 0   |
     "P5" , 60 , 80 , 80 , 80      , 0   |
     "P6" , 100, 100, 100, 100     , 25  |
     "P7" , 90 , 100, 80 , NA_real_, 50  |
     "P8" , 80 , 100, 100, 80      , 75  |
     "P9" , 25 , 90 , 98 , 95      , 90  |
     "P10", 26 , 35 , 40 , 50      , 35  |
     "P11", 100, 100, 100, 80      , 30  )

my_data_im <- amelia(data.frame(my_data), m = 5, idvars = "ID", emburn = c(0, 1000), bound = rbind(c(5, 0, 100)))

list_im_prep_A <- lapply(my_data_im$imputations, function(x) x %>% select("X4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

`list_im_prep_A <- lapply(my_data_im$imputations, function(x) x%>% select('X4'))` doesn't work when the list of imputed datasets `my_data_im$imputations` contains NA value (should be an issue from the imputation)... Then instead of:

```
list_im_prep_A <- lapply(my_data_im$imputations, function(x) x %>% select("X4"))
```

i did:

```
xo <- as.data.frame(my_data_im$imputations) #converts the list my_data_im$imputations into a dataframe xo

while (sum(is.na(xo))>0) {
  my_data_im <- amelia(data.frame(my_data), m = 5, idvars = "ID", emburn = c(0, 1000), bound = rbind(c(5, 0, 100)))
  xo <- as.data.frame(my_data_im$imputations)
} # run the imputation until the imputed datasets dataframe xo doesn't contain NA value anymore

list_im_prep_A <- select(xo, contains('X4')) #  in a cleaner way, creating a dataframe from xo, containing all the columns named "X4"
```

which works perfectly fine. The code doesn't gets the error message anymore.